# how to disable zoom slider through excel vba?

Tags: excel, zooming, vba

I am looking to disable zoom slider in excel worksheet. I have looked around but couldn't find a solution to it. There are some solutions pointing to setting the zoom to a defined value but none of them caters to disabling the zoom option itself. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

I am adding the code I have put in ThisWorkbook to disable most of the visible option on worksheet.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = Not Application.DisplayStatusBar
ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Hide list of sheets
Call hide_sheets
Windows(1).WindowState = xlMaximized
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = Not Application.DisplayStatusBar
ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100


'Lock cells in the UI sheet
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UI").ScrollArea = "A1:t46"

'Hide scroll bar
With ActiveWindow
    .DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = False
    .DisplayVerticalScrollBar = False
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
welcomeScreen.Show 0

End Sub
```

Some screen shots of the problem I am facing. I am currently using some makeshift arrangement by loading the maximized version userform on workbook opening. So the slider is hidden.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide the zoom slider alone you can do so by editing the registry key

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Excel\StatusBar`

by setting `ZoomSlider` value to `0`

Anyway, i don't think this can be achieved using VBA even with `SaveSetting`.

You can try write a `.reg` file to change the target key and VBA-load it. I'm not sure if this can be done but even if it works the user will still to have click Yes in a system prompt to allow the key to be loaded into registry.

And even when the user click Yes to allow the `.reg` file to load and change the registry key, Excel status bar doesn't refresh to show/hide the ZoomSlider, until Excel is restarted.

In short, hiding zoom slider alone using VBA doesn't seem to be achievable.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be a way to disable zoom completely or specifically the slider after looking around. If you're main mission is to avoid someone clicking on the zoom slider I would probably go with hiding the statusbar all together.

```
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
```

Comment: tried it, but the slider still appears. I have tried right clicking on the bar (portion of window where slider appears). After clicking a box opens and zoom slider has a tick option next to it. When it is unchecked the slider disappears.

Comment: @ashishjain - are you sure you are not seeing the slider from another application. I tested this for another project I am doing and it worked great.

Comment: @ Scott. Please see the attached screenshots. Let me know if there is a possible solution for it. Thanks